# MacOS keeps asking for System Keychain

Tags: password, keychain, login

Keeps asking me for my keychain password. Here's what I've tried!

- Reset my default keychains
- Enter my login password
- Says "Created a new empty “login” keychain with no password. Please change password using 
  Edit.
- Changed the login keychain. Can access that fine.
- Restart mac
- After logging back in there are several prompts for the login keychain which I get past
- When opening keychain access again, I unlock the keychain system. It prompts for domain pw.
- If I try to change the access controls to allow all apps to access the vpn, it asks for the system keychain again, which I don't know.

I don't know what to do. Can someone please help!

Comment: Is this your MacBook or was it issued by a company to you?

Comment: Issued by my company. We have an admin login but it's not working for me either.

Comment: Then you need to consult with the the IT person in your company. We can’t “break” keychains

Comment: Post as an answer!

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue, but its cause was different.

In my case, the request always appeared when starting the Mail app. After trying a lot of things including repairing permission and clearing NVRAM, it turned out that the user had an S/MIME certificate and private key for email encryption which was stored in the *system* keychain, but should be stored in the *login* keychain.

I exported the certificate and its private key, deleted it from the system keychain, and then re-imported it to the login keychain. (Perhaps it would have been possible to simply move it there – didn't try that.)

After a reboot and starting the Mail app, a request appeared to allow access to the login keychain which I acknowledged with "Always allow". After that, the problem was gone.

Answer (score 0):

Delete my keychain cookies and after I was good. Took two seconds to fix after me spending hours to troubleshoot it myself.

Comment: Which are "keychain cookies" and where did you delete them from?

Comment: Never heard of keychain cookies. What are they and how to delete them?